Scrape text and href from hyperlinks in Puppeteer
I am writing a html to scrape data by puppeteer from internet with the code below:
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async ()=>
{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()

    await page.goto("https://www.info.gov.hk/gia/wr/202404/26.htm")

    const bulletin_urls = await page.$$('div.leftBody');

    for(const bulletin_url of bulletin_urls)
    {
        try
        {
            const bulletin_name = await page.evaluate(el => el.textContent, bulletin_url)
            console.log(bulletin_name)

            const single_url = await page.evaluate(el => el.getAttribute("href"), bulletin_url)
            console.log(single_url) 
        }
        catch(err)
        {
        
        }
    }
    await browser.close()
}) ();

I want to scrape 2 information of ALL PRESS WEATHER:

the name of the bulletins
the url of the Hyperlink.

I succeed when scraping 1 while fail at 2. What I get is simply null. I try to amend my code to
const single_url = await page.evaluate(el => el.querySelector(".NEW").getAttribute("href"), bulletin_url)
console.log(single_url)

However, it just returns me the first but not all url. What shall I do to collect all the url of the hyperlink at one command? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

You're selecting the container but not the specific elements within it. Try doing that:
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^22.7.1

const url = "<Your URL>";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on("request", req => {
    req.url() === url ? req.continue() : req.abort();
  });
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const data = await page.$$eval(".NEW", els => els.map(el => ({
    text: el.textContent,
    href: el.href,
  })));
  console.log(data);
  console.log(data.length); // => 125
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());

Most of the code here is disabling JS and blocking resource requests, because the data is right there in the static HTML, meaning you don't need Puppeteer. Just use Fetch (built in to Node now) and Cheerio (a lightweight HTML parser).
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // ^1.0.0-rc.12

const url = "<Your URL>";

fetch(url)
  .then(res => {
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw Error(res.statusText);
    }

    return res.text();
  })
  .then(html => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const data = [...$(".NEW")].map(e => ({
      text: $(e).text(),
      href: $(e).attr("href"),
    }));
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.length);
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

Puppeteer unoptimized (without any blocks, with JS and without {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"}:
real 0m4.180s
user 0m0.981s
sys  0m0.198s

Puppeteer optimized (as shown above):
real 0m1.181s
user 0m0.642s
sys  0m0.171s

Fetch and Cheerio:
real 0m0.426s
user 0m0.194s
sys  0m0.045s

Important: never use catch (err) {} with an empty block unless you really want to stifle errors. In this case, you're debugging a script, so the last thing you want to do is throw away important debugging information.
Also, avoid element handles. They're verbose, slow and prone to error. There's no need to use them except for issuing trusted events, which aren't typically needed in web scraping, except for occasionally filling out forms that require event handlers to fire. $$eval is the way to go 95% of the time. It's a one-shot trip to the browser to get your data and get out.
